# How to serve the css, javascript and images locally from apache httpd

Tags: java, apache, apache2

Currently I'm working frontend part of the web application. I'm accessing the remote url through which i can able to test the front end code.

I have apache httpd 2.25 in my system, so from this server i want to serve my local assets through apache httpd to the response of the remote url to test my javascript, css etc.

I tried to do some thing in the httpd.conf file in apache httpd, but i could not able to do it. Kindly give us some idea to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Put the files in the folder specified by DocumentRoot on httpd.conf